# How to create a full working drop menu?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 problem with my drop menu, I cannot open the section "book" (a problem related to the img or text below), I cannot click on 19th books without clicking on book before and "the book as an investment" can I have it in one line ?

It is for an exam, so all the web site is not built and everything should be in Html/Css

Here the code https://jsfiddle.net/q9776ear/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div id="Wrapper">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome Emblem book</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menutest.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <nav id="CommonHeader">
              <li><a href="contactustest.html">Contact us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          </nav>
    <p id="emblem">Emblem</p>
            <img src="images/emblem_logo_160.png" alt="logo" />
            <p id="rare">Rare, Collectible Books</p>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="menutest.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="Books"><a href="bookstest.html">Books</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">20th Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="">19th Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">18th Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rare Books</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a href="deliverytest.html">Delivery</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Books as an investment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div id="MainPart" class="size">
          <section>
            <article id="BookOfTheMonth">
              <img src="images/heart_of_the_matter.jpg" alt="Book of the month" />
              <h3>The Heart of the Matter</h3>
              <h1>Graham Greene 1900 copy. </h1>
              <p>One of only 50 published in this edition. Excellent condition in its original blue cloth with publisher&rsquo;s device stamped on cover. This book represents an excellent investment, and is expected to appreciate in value by 6% over the next three years.</p>
            </article>
            <article id="Rare books">
              <h1>Buying Rare Books</h1>
              <p>Emblem are always looking to buy rare books. We offer very competitive prices for appropriate books. All you need to do is contact us with details of the book or collection you are looking to sell.  We will need to know the following information,<br />
                Author.</br>
                Title (exactly as it appears on the title page).</br>
                Publisher and publication date.</br>
                Edition (if known).</br>
                Brief description of the binding (cloth boards, leather-bound, with or lacking dustwrapper).</br>
                Description of the overall condition of the book,  including any major defects.</br>
                If the book meets our requirements, we will contact you for more details.</p>
            </article>
            <article id="Selling books">
              <h1>Selling Books</h1>
              <p>Emblem sells rare and collectable fiction and poetry. We are particularly interested in 18th and 19th century books, and have a world-renowned stock of latter 19th century women’s writing. Of particular interest are first editions, private press editions, and author signed copies. We also provide a restoration service, and consultancy on investment in rare books. We issue printed and illustrated catalogues of rare books twice a year. We also exhibit at book fairs in the UK, New Zealand, Canada and the USA.</p>
            </article>
            <article id="Value books">
              <h1>Valuing Books</h1>
                <p>If you possess books you wish to sell then a formal valuation the most appropriate course of action. Emblem undertakes written valuations for insurance purposes or personal interest. We can appraise a single books or collections. If you wish to have a book valued, a free initial verbal assessment of whether the book is likely to have sufficient value to merit a full valuation is recommended. If you decide to go ahead with the valuation, Emblem will provide you with an estimate of the cost before the valuation is carried out in full. Fees for valuation work are charged at a half day rate of £300.</p>
            </article>
          </section>
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="videos/emblem_video_480x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="videos/emblem_video_480x360.ogg" type="video/ogg">
              <source src="videos/emblem_video_480x360.webm" type="video/webm">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </footer>
 </body>
</html>

    And Css:


/*Logo design */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'parisian';
  src: url('fonts/parisr.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/parisr.ttf') format('ttf'),
       url('fonts/parisr.svg') format('svg'),
       url('fonts/parisr.eot') format('eot');
}
#emblem{
 font-family:'parisian', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left:56px;
  top:5px;
}
#rare{
font-family:'parisian', arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 left:13px;
 top: 98px;
 }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #236841;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display:list-item;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}

.size{
width: 95%;
padding: 10px;
text-align: justify;
margin:auto;
position: static;
}

article{
     width: 65%;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     padding: 10px;
     position: relative;
     margin: 10px;
     left: 16.25%;
}


/*******************************************
   Style menu for larger screens

   Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
   or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align:center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
video{
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 32.5%;
}
footer{
  background-color:#236841;
}
footer li a{
  color:black;
}
footer li{
    display:none;
}
/*Delivery page */
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
footer{
  background-color:#236841;
}
footer li a{
  color:black;
}
footer li{
    display: inline;
}
/*header design  */
#CommonHeader li{
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't function. Something is being blocked. Please click the Tidy button and follow the suggestions.

Comment: Your `head` and `body` are inside your `<div id="Wrapper">`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q9776ear/1/ updated version

Comment: Looks like you still didn't click the `Tidy` button isherwood suggested.

Comment: I did, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your biggest issue, not being able to click the sub-menu item:

Add a `z-index: 9;` to your `.nav li ul` style rule, and it'll be clickable.